# How to fix width of radio button

Tags: html, css

I would like to style a radio button with pure css. I almost got it but I can´t make the background color with a fixed width.

This is what I am achieving...

[image: berore]

...and this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: after]

Here is my html

```
<form>

<a>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="mode" value="size" class="button"> 
<span><label for="radio1">Varones</label></span>
</a>

<a>     
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="mode" value="count" checked> 
<span><label for="radio2">Mujeres</label></span>
</a>

<a>
<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="mode" value="count" checked>
<span><label for="radio3"> Ambos</label></span>
</a>

</form>
```

Here is my css

```
span {
    width: 100px;
}

a {

    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    display: block;
    padding:7px;
    display:block;
}

label {
    width:150px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + span {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background: lightblue; /*fondo del boton inactivo*/
    color: black;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    padding-right:50px;
    color: red; /*color tipografia boton activo*/
    background: url('flechaRadio.png') right no-repeat;
    background-color:#E5E5E5;/* color fondo boton activo*/ 
    background-position: 70px;
}

input[type="radio"]:hover + label:hover {
    color: black; /*estilo para la tipo del over */
}
```

Here is the example

http://jsfiddle.net/ploscri/P9yer/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `display:inline-block` to your spans and remove the padding from the checked option:

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9yer/1/)**

Comment: @Pablo Glad to help. Don't forget to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking on the green check mark to the left

Comment: Probably be better to specify the width in `em` rather than `px` so the label text doesn't get cut off if the user has specified custom font settings in their browser.